# How to get split string with quotation on each split item in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to get split string with quotation on each split item in SQL Server? I have tried this

```
declare @departmentNames as varchar(max) = 'Account, hod'
--declare @departmentNames as varchar(max) = 'Account'+', '+'hod'
print @departmentNames
```

I get result like this => `Account,hod`

but I want it like this => `'Account', 'hod'`

so that I could use it in

```
select * 
from tblDepartment 
where name in (select item from splitString(@departmentNames, ','))
```

I know if I use integers with id column it will work fine i.e  => 1, 2, 3, 4 but I want to try it with strings.

So is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select td.*
from tblDepartment td cross apply
     <shema>.splitString(@departmentNames, ',') spt(item) -- add schema name 
where spt.item = td.name;
```

If you want string comparison, you can do concatenation.

Note : use Schema name while calling `UDF` function.

Answer (score 1):

First create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split]
     (@String varchar(8000), 
      @Delimiter varchar(50))          
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))          
AS
BEGIN
    /*  
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Split('12345;thome', ';')  
    */          
    DECLARE @idx int          
    DECLARE @slice varchar(8000)          
    DECLARE @delimiterLength int  

    SET @delimiterLength = len(@Delimiter)  

    SELECT @idx = 1          

    IF LEN(@String) < 1 OR @String IS NULL
        RETURN

    WHILE @idx != 0          
    BEGIN
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)          

        IF @idx != 0
            SET @slice = LEFT(@String, @idx - 1)          
        ELSE
            SET @slice = @String          

        IF (LEN(@slice) > 0)     
            INSERT INTO @temptable(Items) 
            VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@slice)))

        SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @idx - @delimiterLength + 1)          
        IF LEN (@String) = 0 
             BREAK
    END

    RETURN
END
```

After creating this function then you can test with below query.

It splits words with any delimiter you are passing

```
   select  items  from dbo.fn_Split('ACCOUNT ,HOD',',')
   select  items  from dbo.fn_Split('ACCOUNT ; HOD',';')
```

Then pass variable and and use join with this function.

Use table alias for easy understanding

```
declare @departmentNames as varchar(max) = ('Account,     hod')

 select t.* 
 from tblDepartment t
 inner join 
     (Select items 
      from dbo.fn_Split (@departmentNames, ',')) A on t.name = A.items
```

I create temptable for testing  and this query will return output like below

[image]